# Send Proxies to a URL vb.net

Tags: vb.net, url, proxy, proxies

Hello does anyone know how I can send proxies to a URL in vb.net?

Like if I put a proxy in a textbox it will be sent to the URL when I click a button, any help? Thanks.

Comment: Did you search related to your question online or did you try any code?

Answer (score 0):

Set the proxy property of your WebClient or HttpWebRequest object ( depends on what you use ) to `New System.Net.WebProxy("host", 8888)`

You can replace host with txtHost.Text and 8888 to txtPort.Text where txtHost is TextBox that handles the proxy host and txtPort is TextBox that handles proxy port.